# One API to get Virtual Guest information

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using the following API's to get information about a particular virtual Guest. Can some one help me get the information with one single api by combining the following?

To get VM's operating system:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/$virtualGuestID/getOperatingSystem
```

Similarly To get the PoD
`getFrontendRouters`

Get provisioned date for a VM
`getProvisionDate`

Get attached Network Storage
`getAttachedNetworkStorages`

Replacing $virtualGuestID with the actual VM ID

Answer (score 1):

You can use object masks:

```
GET https://$USERNAME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/$VSIID/getObject?objectMask=mask[provisionDate,operatingSystem,frontendRouters,allowedNetworkStorage]
```

Regards

Comment: Thank You Nelson, it did help me

Comment: great can you please mark the answer as the correct thanks in advance